# Asp.net code fails to call javascript function

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

This is the code to call the javascript function from asp.net code:

**aspx File:**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Restaurants.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm1" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function alertMe() {
            alert('Hello');
        }
    </script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="body" runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
```

**aspx.cs File:**

```
     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (!Page.IsPostBack)
                {
                    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "CallMyFunction","alertMe()", true);
                 }
               }
```

Problem: The asp.net code fails to call javascript function
I searched for the solution few links are:
http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=273
[Calling JavaScript Function From CodeBehind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5731224/calling-javascript-function-from-codebehind)
http://www.devcurry.com/2009/01/execute-javascript-function-from-aspnet.html

but could not find the solution. Can anyone help me.

**PAGE SOURCE**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="../css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/heroic-features.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../css/jasny-bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrapValidator.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/dist/bootstrapValidator.min.css" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500">
    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) 
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>-->
    <!-- jQuery Version 1.11.0 -->
    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jasny-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrapValidator.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/dist/bootstrapValidator.min.js"></script>
     <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500">
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=places"></script>
    <script>
        // This example displays an address form, using the autocomplete feature
        // of the Google Places API to help users fill in the information.

        var placeSearch, autocomplete;
        var componentForm = {
            street_number: 'short_name',
            route: 'long_name',
            locality: 'long_name',
            administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
            country: 'long_name',
            postal_code: 'short_name'
        };

        function initialize() {
            // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search
            // to geographical location types.
            autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
            /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
      { types: ['geocode'] });
            // When the user selects an address from the dropdown,
            // populate the address fields in the form.
            google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {
                fillInAddress();
            });
        }

        // [START region_fillform]
        function fillInAddress() {
            // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
            var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

            for (var component in componentForm) {
                document.getElementById(component).value = '';
                document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
            }

            // Get each component of the address from the place details
            // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
            for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
                var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
                if (componentForm[addressType]) {
                    var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
                    document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
                }
            }
        }
        // [END region_fillform]

        // [START region_geolocation]
        // Bias the autocomplete object to the user's geographical location,
        // as supplied by the browser's 'navigator.geolocation' object.
        function geolocate() {
            if (navigator.geolocation) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
                    var geolocation = new google.maps.LatLng(
          position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
                    autocomplete.setBounds(new google.maps.LatLngBounds(geolocation,
          geolocation));
                });
            }
        }
        // [END region_geolocation]

    </script>





    <script type="text/javascript">
        function alertMe() {
            alert('Hello');
        }
    </script>


</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="Home.aspx">Home</a>
            </div>
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    </nav>
    <!-- Page Content -->
    <div class="container">

    <!-- Page Content -->


        <hr>
     </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "The asp.net code fails to call javascript function" - what does this mean? Have you looked at the browser's page source html? Have you found `alertMe` definition and call there?

Comment: Nope  `alertMe` haven't called by asp.net code.

Comment: Could you show us the entire html page (you can use the `View page source`)?

Comment: If it is not postback there will be two javascript blocks in the markup with function definition and call. Do you see them both? Are there any script errors on the page?

Comment: I have updated the query. Please view the page source code

Comment: @victork nope there are no script errors

Comment: Have you tried to wrap the javascript function in a document ready?
Something like
<script>function alertMe(){ alert('Hello');} $(alertMe);</script>

Comment: I think you must add <form runat="server"> to the page. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6602650/will-clientscript-registerstartupscript-work-only-in-forms

Comment: @Zaphod yes i tried this too :(

Comment: @victork you got that :) Thanks - You can write this as answer

Comment: your method call is not in your page source

Comment: Maybe postbacking the page interrupts js ?

Answer (score 1):

Im not exactly sure how to call it from the cs code, but couldn't you put something like this is your aspx page?

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function alertMe() {
        alert('Hello');
    }

var isPostBack = '<%=Page.IsPostBack%>' == 'True' ? true : false;

if (!isPostBack){
   alertMe();
}
</script>
```